# Default ping timeout

Tags: c#, ping

What is the default time of ping? I use the code below to send ping to tcp devices. When does IPStatus fall to timeout?

```
private static void ApplyPing(Topology.Runtime rt)
{
    try
    {
        if (rt.TcpClient != null)
        {
            string ip = rt.Ip;
            if (new Ping().Send(ip).Status != IPStatus.Success)
            {
                Service.WriteEventLog(string.Format("{0} ping error.", ip), EventLogEntryType.Warning);
                rt.Disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
    { 

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Service.WriteEventLog(ex, EventLogEntryType.Error);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What did you measure?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb7xxkfx.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hzczzed.aspx)

> The method waits five seconds for an ICMP echo reply message. If it does not receive a reply in that time, the method returns and the Status property is set to TimedOut.

And if we check in reflector, indeed we see:

```
public PingReply Send(string hostNameOrAddress)
{
    return this.Send(hostNameOrAddress, 5000, this.DefaultSendBuffer, null);
}
```

Comment: Is there a possible way to override the 5 second value?

Comment: @Harold_Finch not AFAIK

Comment: What does "AFAIK" mean?

Comment: @Harold_Finch "as far as I know"

Comment: On [latest .Net version](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/NetworkInformation/ping.cs,272) there's an override to specify the timeout